# Radio no longer works after short circuting the lighter

Tags: electrical

The previous owner of my 1998 Toyota Avalon thought it was a good idea to touch the two power cables on the lighter (which he had disassembled for a reason I don't know). The radio doesn't work and neither does the back lights on the dashboard under the gauges. The other lights on my dash including the check engine light and oil lights work. I checked the 15 amp fuse labeled number 35 in the fuse box and it looked fine. There was also one other fuse under the hood but that one also looked fine. What went wrong?

Comment: Welcome to rhe site. Check all of the fuses. It could be you're misreading the layout of the fuse box. Cigarette lighter and radio are regularly on the same fuse. Also, if expect it to be at least a 20A fuse.

Comment: I'll try and find some other diagrams and see if they are different. The amps on all the fuses match up with the site but I will check again. They seem to be labeled 15AMP

Comment: You may need to actually test the fuses for continuity. Sometimes they can fail in a way you can't see. Ensure you are getting power on the positive side of the fuse. Lastly, check to ensure your ground side for the lighter and radio, etc. are still good. The previous owner may have broken a ground wire.